# backwards shift of R not injective

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers

So my book states the following:

$R = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} = \{ a = (a_0, a_1,a_2,....)\, | \, a_i  \in  
\mathbb{R} \}$

Lets say we have an image $$s: R \rightarrow R, \quad (a_0, a_1, ... ) \mapsto 
(a_1, a_2,...)$$ 
This image is not an injection, but it is a surjection.

> I get that it is a surjection but how can it be not a injection?

---

I think like this:
$a_0$ maps to $a_1$, $a_1$ maps to $a_2$,..... There are no elements of the domain that map to the same element in the codomain...

Please can somebody just give a simple explanation to help me understand this example? I am feeling I'm missing something crucial but simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $s$  is not injective means there exist distinct $a$ and $b$ in the domain so that $s(a)=s(b)$. Now what is the image of $a=(1,2,3,4,...)$ and $b=(2,2,3,4,....)$ ?

Comment: (2,3,4,.... ) Wooooow. I'm stupid! I totally get it now! Thanks!